# How to access a String Array location in android?

Tags: android, exception

Android 2.3.3

This is my code...

```
String[] expression = {""}; //globally declared as empty

somewhere in the code below, I am trying to assign a string to it.

expression[0] = "Hi";

I keep getting the following error...
12-08 22:12:19.063: E/AndroidRuntime(405): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
```

Can someone help me with this..
Can we access the index 0, directly as i am doing?

Actual Code :::

```
static int x = 0; // global declaration
String[] assembledArray = {""}; // global declaration

assembleArray(strSubString, expression.charAt(i)); //Passing string to the method

//Method Implementation
private void assembleArray(String strSubString, char charAt) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        assembledArray[x] = strSubString;
        assembledArray[x+1] = String.valueOf(charAt);
        x = x+2;

    }
```

Comment: Working fine for me: http://ideone.com/WERQ3H... can you please show the full code from creation to modification?

Comment: @Eric ::: Edited the question with code..

Comment: @Bhavik Ambani ::: It is used to increment the array index. At first it will be zero and as the array builds up, x will help in accessing the array indexes

Comment: String[] expression = {""}; must be: String[] expression = new String[]{""};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in `assembledArray[x]`; it's in `assembledArray[x+1]`.

At the first iteration, `x+1 = 1`, so you cannot access that part of the array. I would suggest using a dynamic array, aka an `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<String> assembledArray = new ArrayList<String>(); // global declaration

assembleArray(strSubString, expression.charAt(i)); //Passing string to the method

//Method Implementation
private void assembleArray(String strSubString, char charAt) {
    assembledArray.add(strSubString);
    assembledArray.add(String.valueOf(charAt));
}
```

This way, Java takes care of the resizing, and you don't need to keep track of `x`.

Comment: Ok.. But can you tell me, why I cannot access the index x+1?

Comment: Arrays do not resize themselves in Java. Your array is of length 1, so it only has index `0`. When you attempt to access index `1`, that is out of bounds (bounds are 0 to 0), so Java gives up and throws an exception.